# Angular ng repeat and filter in dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi Can you please help me i have a situation in angular js to load a occuaption dropdown based on age for different members, please see me code snipet.

```
<select selectpicker ng-model="data.dataRequest.members[$index].occupation" 
   ng-options="occ.key as occ.value for occ in Lov.occupation track by occ.key">
```

I want to write something like this,

But I see the comaprison operator is not working in the filter, I even wrote a custom filter but still no use. Please help.

Comment: I want to write something like this,                                                                             <select selectpicker ng-model="data.dataRequest.members[$index].occupation" 
 ng-options="occ.key as occ.value for occ in Lov.occupation track by occ.key | filter:occ.age< data.dataRequest.members[$index].age ">

Comment: A plunker would also help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` pipe to dynamically filter out list of occupations

```
<select ng-model="data.dataRequest.members[$index].occupation" 
   ng-options="occ.key as occ.value for occ in Lov.occupation | filter: myCoolFiter track by occ.key">
```

in controller:

```
$scope.age = 13;    
$scope.myCoolFiter = function(occupationItem){
       // return true or false based on the logic
       // for ex: return occupationItem.fromAge < $scope.age && $scope.age < occupationItem.toAge; 
}
```

However, to be able to use `filter` pipe in your template, `Lov.occupation` should be array, not object

**Note**

`myCoolFilter` is called by angular `filter` pipe for each item in the array.  `filter` pipe has following parameter list `function(value, index, array)`. Here is the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) for more details

Comment: Thats correct. I was getting that error cannot be an object. Let me try adn will get back to you thanks guys.

Comment: If my answer helped, I hope you re-consider the accepted answer

Comment: I was able to filter the occupation, only thing left pending is, I want to pass a parameter the filter function which I am not able to do now.<select ng-model="data.dataRequest.members[$index].occupation" 
   ng-options="occ.key as occ.value for occ in Lov.occupation | filter: myCoolFiter(age) track by occ.key">. Can you please help.

Comment: Since only angular itself calls `myCoolFilter`, you cannot pass parameters to it. `filter` pipe has following parameter list `function(value, index, array)`. Here is the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). However, what you can do is to store `age` as `$scope` variable

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your object in your controller maybe.  just change your object to array.
To do so :
   `$scope.newTable = []`

```
`$scope.occupation.forEach(function(item) { newTable.push(item) })`
```

`$scope.occupation = newTable`

Comment: Getting the below error in the filter,                                                                                                                                    Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'track' is an unexpected token at column 36 of the expression [occ.key | filter: occupationFilter track by occ.key] starting at [track by occ.key].

Comment: the track by has to be declared before the filter i guess , try : 
... track by occ.key | filter : occupationFilter

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have combined both the answers and got it working. Now my filter is working.